# Updating cp-schema-registry:3.2.2 to 6.2.0 ends in a cleanup policy issue

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm updating a docker-compose file the cp-schema-registry:3.2.2 to 6.2.0. Zookeeper cp-zookeeper image and cp-kafka will updated as well.

If the file is restarted the schema-registry complains about a policy which is expected:

```
[2021-08-24 10:19:41,630] ERROR The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect. You must configure the topic to 'compact' cleanup policy to avoid Kafka deleting your schemas after a week. Refer to Kafka documentation for more details on cleanup policies (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
```

If I set this policy in the Kafka image cp-kafka:6.2.0 `KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: compact` on the first glance it seems to be work.

The docker-compose system seems to be set-up. The docker-compose file sends a lot of topics to the broker.

After this sending a topic to Kafka, the broker starts to complain.

```
The system will be filled with topics and at the end the broker complains about:
[2021-08-20 09:05:55,019] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition my-topic-bus-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException: One or more records have been rejected
```

and

```
2021-08-20 07:55:28.543  WARN 8 --- [ad | producer-2] org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Errors  : Unexpected error code: 87.
```

If figured out that 87 means

```
INVALID_RECORD(87, "This record has failed the validation on broker and hence will be rejected.", InvalidRecordException::new),
```

I really wonder about the issue that the `KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: delete` is set in Kafka and the default value. Further the schema-registry starts to complain. Googleing around, reading here, reading there, asking some collegues I didn't get an understanding what the root of the problem is and how to solve it. Has anybody an idea to delete the topics still as clean up policy?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have read all the release and upgrade notes for both [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_7_0) and Confluent Platform between those two versions? There have been several internal Kafka topic format changes that need resolved (e.g. `log.message.format.version` + `inter.broker.protocol.version`).

If you've not worked through those configs, then that explains your errors and will affect more than just the Registry.

---

You shouldn't modify the default cleanup policy for *all topics* to fix just the `_schemas` topic.

Instead you should start up the broker only, then use `kafka-topics --alter --topic _schemas` to modify it, then start the Registry once you use `kafka-topics --describe --topic _schemas` and see `cleanup.policy=compact`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was indeed the `_schema` topic. There was a fourth service - a company internal - in the game. When all services are started to the same time there was a race condition. The fourth service sends immediately topics to the schema registry which I didn't know and this was the reason for the error message. By setting this variable inside the broker section to `KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE` to `: "false"` solved the race condition.